# How to get current product id from custom block?

Tags: commerce

I've problem to get current product id from custom block displayed on product page. Here my code :

```
class TestBlock extends BlockBase {


  public function build() {


$product = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

$productid = $product->product_id();

return array(
 '#markup' => $this->t('Product ID : ') . '<h2>' . $productid . '</h2>',      

    );
  }

}
```

Do you have any idea to get the current ID from product ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to get product ID

```
$product_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_product')->id();
```

and then return the value in custom block,

```
return [      
      '#product_id' =>  $product_id,
    ];
```

Comment: Careful, `getParameter` will return `NULL` if there's no product and the page will die with a fatal error when you try to use it as an object

Comment: can we set condition for checking null values?

Comment: Yeah of course. `id()` is lowercase too BTW

Comment: It's work, thank you :) But i have now a problem with cache. Need to clear it to get the correct product id. How i can fix it ?

Comment: ok clive, i will change it

Comment: @Webman You need to vary the cache of your render array, probably by path (`url.path`). See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts for more info

Comment: Hello, To fix the cache probIem i added this line "'#cache' => array('max-age' => 0),"

Answer (score 0):

Like, such code should work:

```
$product_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('commerce_product');
```

But in my case it is not working. But it work:

```
$paramList = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameters();
foreach($paramList as $paramName=>$paramVal) {
    // save params to any variables...
}
```